# Tirarsela, cosa significa?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, single-words

Buongiorno,

Come spiegheresti ad uno straniero il significato della parola tirarsela?

Grazie.

Comment: Che problemi ci sono con la definizione del dizionario? ("assumere un atteggiamento di superiorità" nel Treccani)

Comment: Credo che l'equivalente inglese sia _to show off_ oppure _to brag_

Answer (score 3):

Non ho capito bene se voglia sapere come spiegarlo in italiano o in inglese. Tra vedere e non vedere te lo dico in entrambi i modi.

**Italiano**
In italiano significa ‘vantarsi’, ‘atteggiarsi’,  [“darsi arie”, “assumere un atteggiamento di superiorità”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tirare/).

> Quindi è un termine usato per descrivere l’atteggiamento di una persona che si atteggia a superiore, che si vanta ed è sprezzante nei confronti delle altre persone.

**Inglese**
‘Tirarsela’ in English means “to show off”, “to be snobby”, “to have an attitude”.

> A person who “se la tira” is someone who has an attitude, who despises others and brags about being better than other people.

Un chiaro esempio che mi viene in mente che rende bene l’idea è rappresentato dall’atteggiamento dei [dandy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dandy) dell’Ottocento, fortemente interessati alla loro apparenza e sprezzanti nei confronti degli altri (un esempio di dandy è Dorian Gray).